# How do I use backticks to capture the elapsed time output from time(1)?

Tags: perl, time

I’m trying to get the output from [`time`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man1/time.1.html) with the following command. The only thing that I want is get the elapsed time, but I get nothing.

```
$result = `/usr/bin/time -f %e "./"$PROG > /dev/null`;
print $result;
```

Comment: Remove the `> /dev/null` ?

Comment: This is the redirection of the command that I'm trying to get the elapsed time with the command /usr/bin/time.

Comment: @Andomar time writes to `stderr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The redirection needed is just a bit tricky.

```
my $result = `/usr/bin/time -f %e "./"$PROG 2>&1 >/dev/null`;
```

`time` outputs its measurement on the standard error (file descriptor 2), but Perl backticks capture the standard *output* (file descriptor 1). Read the redirection sequence above as “first send the standard error to the standard output’s destination and then throw away the original standard output.”

The answer to [How can I capture `STDERR` from an external command?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f) in the Perl FAQ addresses the issue you’re seeing.

> To capture a command’s `STDERR` but discard its `STDOUT`:
>
> ```
> $output = `cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null`;           # either with backticks
> $pid = open(PH, "cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null |");  # or with an open pipe
> while (<PH>) { }                            #    plus a read
> ```
>
> … Ordering is important in all these examples. That’s because the shell processes file descriptor redirections in strictly left to right order.
>
> ```
> system("prog args 1>tmpfile 2>&1");
> system("prog args 2>&1 1>tmpfile");
> ```
>
> The first command sends both standard out and standard error to the temporary file. The second command sends only the old standard output there, and the old standard error shows up on the old standard out.

Note that `$result` will contain a trailing newline, which you can remove with `chomp` as in

```
chomp $result;
```

or all in a single line with

```
chomp(my $result = `/usr/bin/time -f %e "./"$PROG 2>&1 >/dev/null`);
```

Comment: No. If you redirect stderr into stdout and then redirect stdout to /dev/null you still get nothing.

Comment: Drat. You're right. It's closing and duping file descriptors, not pointers.  How embarrassing.

Comment: I prefer [this one](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20can%20I%20capture%20STDERR%20from%20an%20external%20command%3F)